# UbuntuOne Thunderbird Filelink and big files

Tags: ubuntu-one, thunderbird

I can't upload big attachments in Mozilla Thunderbird. I'm using filelink feature. I can upload small files, but not big one (200MB). Is it some restrictions to file size?

Answer (score 0):

Not any restriction that I would be aware... 
Is there any relevant message in the "Error console" located in the "Tools" menu?

Comment: Weird, tried again and now works - 180 MB file. Maybe some network issue. Thank you

Comment: Timestamp: 31.8.2012 12:51:31
Error: 504 - Gateway Time-out
Source File: resource:///modules/http.jsm
Line: 47

Probably
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/1041880

Answer (score 0):

I had a file that would not work, and assumed it was a network issue at first.  Turned out it was because there was a comma in the file name, so unusual characters in the file's name would be one thing to check for.